# Customize LESS grid variable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to customize the grid system so that the max width of the page should be 724px. I've tried messing around with the LESS variables in bootstrap homepage:

[image]

But I'm getting an error.txt inside the css folder each time. What am I doing wrong and is this even the right approach to achieve what I want?

Comment: I think it is not your fault. If you enter the original values it will still produce an error file...

Answer (score 0):

As per @BalintoBako comment, I tried downloading with the default settings and have an error.txt file in the CSS folder (only). The contents of the error file are:

> A less error occured trying to build your bundle. You've likely
>   entered an invalid input into the less variable field. Check your
>   syntax and try again!
>
> thanks!
>
> {"type":"Parse","message":"Syntax Error on line
>   4196","index":109655,"filename":"bootstrap.css","line":4196,"column":0,"extract":["}","","

Looks like this isn't your fault, again as Balint Bako stated.

(this would have been a comment, but the formatting required for the blockquote was not allowed)